# Issue in call two fragment at a same time in SlidingTabLayout viewpager with FragmentStatePagerAdapter android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

Hello friends i have SlidingTabLayout viewpager so below is my code

**main.xml**

```
<slider.SlidingTabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/pager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

**Main.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// Declaring Your View and Variables
private Toolbar toolbar;
private ViewPager pager;
private ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
private SlidingTabLayout tabs;
private CharSequence Titles[] = {"Calls", "Chats", "Contacts" };
int Numboftabs = 3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Creating The Toolbar and setting it as the Toolbar for the activity

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles
    // fot the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), Titles,
            Numboftabs);

    // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
    tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true);
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);
}
```

}

**ViewPagerAdapter.java**

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

CharSequence Titles[];
int NumbOfTabs;

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, CharSequence mTitles[],
                        int mNumbOfTabsumb) {
    super(fm);
    this.Titles = mTitles;
    this.NumbOfTabs = mNumbOfTabsumb;
}

// This method return the fragment for the every position in the View Pager
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new Call();

        case 1:
            return new Chat();
        case 2:
            return new Contact();

    }
    return null;
}

// This method return the titles for the Tabs in the Tab Strip
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return Titles[position];
}

// This method return the Number of tabs for the tabs Strip
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return NumbOfTabs;
}
```

}

**Call.java**

```
  public class Call extends Fragment {


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.call, container, false);

    return v;
}
```

}

**Chat.java**

```
 public class Chat extends Fragment {


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.call, container, false);

    return v;
   }
```

}

**Contact.java**

```
  public class Contact extends Fragment {


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.call, container, false);

    return v;
}
```

}

When i run above code initially two fragment call like **Call.java** and **Chat.java**, when i scroll left to right and move to **Chat.java** at that time **Contact.java** will call in background  but **i want to call each fragment when he visible on screen** so any idea how can i solve this ?

Comment: did you resolve it if yes then post your answer